WordPress Contact Form 7 redirect based on specific dates
In a WordPress site I need to be able to show a page informing that a prize has been won by sending information through a form.
The system works as follows: there is a form made with Contact Form 7 plugin, that saves through the plugin ‘Post My CF7 Form’ a record in a CPT with the form data.
I need that on certain dates (13 in total, one per week) the first form that is sent after each of the dates shows a page indicating that a prize has been won.
For example, if the first date is ‘2024/05/30 16:00’, the first person who submits the form after that date (ex: ‘2024/05/30 16:04’) will be redirected to the ‘PRIZE’ page. The second person to submit the form after that date (ex: ‘2024/05/30 20:10’) will be redirected to the ‘KEEP TRYING’ page. And so on until the next winning date (‘2024/06/4 11:00’). And so on.
The redirection is easy, but I can't seem to establish the winners over time.
I have tried the following:
<script>
            let currentDate = new Date();
            currentDateP = Date.parse(currentDate);
            let date1 = new Date('2024-05-24T12:00:00');
            date1P = Date.parse(date1);
            let award1 = 0;

            document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
                if ( currentDateP > date1P && award1 == 0 ) {
                    location = 'https://www.example.net/award';
                    award1 = 1;
                    console.log('AWARD!');
                } else if ( currentDateP > date1P && award1 == 1 ){ 
                    location = 'https://www.example.net/thanks';
                    console.log('KEEP TRYING');
                } else {
                    location = 'https://www.example.net/thanks';
                    console.log('KEEP TRYING');
                }
            }, false );
        </script>

As a plus it would be interesting to be able to mark the winning records somehow. I use ACF.

UPDATE & SOLVED *

Like @CBroe said, JavaScript-only approach makes little sense here. I neeed something like an "global variable". Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) was the solution.
I have used a ACF Repeater field ('pv_opt_moments') in an Options Page with two sub-fields: "awarded moment" ('pv_opt_moment_date') and if it used or not ('pv_opt_moment_used').
$awardedList = get_field('pv_opt_moments','option');
$post_id = "option";
    
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");
$date_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$currentDate = strtotime($date_now);
            
$date1 = strtotime($awardedList[0]['pv_opt_moment_date']);
$used1 = $awardedList[0]['pv_opt_moment_used'];
    
$date2 = strtotime($awardedList[1]['pv_opt_moment_date']);
$used2 = $awardedList[1]['pv_opt_momento_used'];

Then, using a conditional, I check whether the current date and time is greater than each of the awarded times and whether or not it is used. I load a script depending on each situation.
<?php if ( $currentDate > $date1 && $used1 == "no"):?>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/award.js"></script>
    <?php update_sub_field( array('pv_opt_moments', 1, 'pv_opt_moment_used'), 'yes', $post_id );?>
<?php elseif ($currentDate > $date2 && $used2 == "no"):?>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/award.js"></script>
    <?php update_sub_field( array('pv_opt_moments', 2, 'pv_opt_moment_used'), 'yes', $post_id );?>
<?php elseif ( $used1 == "yes" || $used2 == "yes":?>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/keep.js"></script>
<?php else:?>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/keep.js"></script>
<?php endif;?>


A JavaScript-only approach makes little sense here. award1 = 1; will have an effect on the current page only - as soon as you send the user to a different page, that assigned value is gone again. Plus, you probably don't want this to work in one specific user's browser only - but across the browsers used by multiple, different users? You need to check when the last form submission happened, by looking at the records this generates, on the server side.

Right @Cbroe. Now I am trying to use a repeater field, with two sub fields in an "Option Page". One with the date and one to indicate if it has been used or not. When the current date is greater than the first ‘awarded moment’ the desired JavaScript will be loaded and using the ‘update_sub_field’ function of ACF I will update the necessary field.
